# Who is this user, who has been removed?

Tags: support

My rep appeared a little strange today morning, to check what was it I went to [reputation tab](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/8482/anshabhi?tab=reputation) and found:

[image]

Who is this user, and why has he been removed?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I lost about 35 points to the same user (or so I assume, as the user seems to have been deleted on the 3rd of July).  Usually people are only removed when something fairly extreme has happened, so...  Yeah, there you go I guess.

Comment: It appears that the removed user had voted a lot as I see removed rep on several different people.

Comment: @JayCarr 35 is 0.59 % of 5900, and 165 is 7.1% of 2300.): :)

Comment: lol, I take it by your response that it doesn't make you feel any better, okay then...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This, ladies and gentlemen, is why you don't create sock puppet users to upvote yourself, and then try to disguise those sock puppets by having them upvote other users. It might not get noticed right away, but eventually you're probably going to get caught, suspended, and have the sock puppet users deleted. When those users are deleted, it not only affects your own reputation, but it negatively affects the random users who's reputation you inflated.

If we all show respect for our fellow community members and play by the rules, this sort of thing doesn't happen.

Just a reminder: Stack Exchange reputation points are not redeemable for cash, hotel stays, or even airline travel. Reputation is largely intended to give you a sense of how much your contributions are appreciated and have helped people, and to give positive reinforcement for continuing engagement. Upvoting yourself is kind of like telling yourself you're the greatest versus getting a genuine compliment. It's cheating yourself as much as it's cheating the community.

Lastly, I'm sorry to the *real* people who were affected in this instance. I hope you understand.

Comment: just a clarification, you don't mean that the sock puppet account was mine... Right?

Comment: by the way,  I can't encash them but Aviation.SE is graduating, and I need **3k** rep to even cast close votes..

Comment: @anshabhi Bret's answer is directed at nobody in particular, but uses "you" in the meaning of "everyone" or "anybody". He could have said: `[...], is why people should not create sock puppet users [...]`

Comment: On stack overflow, reputation can be an asset when getting recruited.

Comment: @Antzi Thats SO, trust me when I say it makes no difference here...

Comment: @anshabhi Aviation is _not_ graduating in the near future. You have lots of time to build reputation.

Answer (score 5):

"Who" is not relevant, relevant is that the account has been closed/deleted (for whatever reason) and that the up/downvotes given by that account have been deleted.

See also:

[What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470)